# Convert arima model to r formula

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I have used `auto.arima` function from R forecast `package` to get 'best' arima model:

```
auto_arima <- forecast::auto.arima(y)
```

The best model I got is 'ARIMA(1,1,0) with drift'.
The question is how can I define this model using an R formula? I need it because I have to use the formula in some other function. Is this right:

```
y ~ diff(y) + # drift?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what that other function is and how to interprets the formula. Normally the right hand side is interpreted as a series of covariates. So you probably want

```
diff(y) ~ lag(y) + 1
```

Note that the fable package uses a formula interface for fitting ARIMA models. In that package, you would specify this model using

```
y ~ 1 + pdq(1,1,0)
```

Comment: I want to use it in strucchange package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/strucchange/vignettes/strucchange-intro.pdf, for function breakpoints. I though difference should be on right hand side and y on left?